# How to use Group By in Marklogic?

Tags: group-by, xquery, marklogic

I want to use Group By in xquery. Can someone tell me please how to use Group By in Marklogic ?

Comment: Haven't used Marklogic. But please have a look at http://blakeley.com/blogofile/archives/560/

Comment: Does the version of MarkLogic you're using support the XQuery 3.0 draft? (It's only as of 3.0 that `group by` support was added to FLWOR expressions; before that point, you have to do it yourself). A summary of `group by` in XQuery 3.0 can be found at http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_3.0#Group_By

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is to use `map:map`. See http://docs.marklogic.com/map:map for documentation, and http://blakeley.com/blogofile/archives/560/ for a longer discussion.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you could call out to XSLT using `xdmp:xslt-invoke` or `xdmp:xslt-eval`. MarkLogic's XSLT processor supports XSLT 2.0, which includes full support for `<xsl:for-each-group>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $xml:= <Students>
    <Student Country="England" Name="Dan" Age="20" Class="C"/>
    <Student Country="England" Name="Maria" Age="20" Class="B" />
    <Student Country="Australia" Name="Mark" Age="22" Class="A" />
  </Students>

let $xsl:= <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
<xsl:template match="Students">
  <result>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Student" group-by="@Country">
    <country>
      <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="fn:current-grouping-key()"/></xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:for-each select="fn:current-group()/@Name">
        <name><xsl:value-of select="."/></name>     
      </xsl:for-each>
    </country>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </result>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

return xdmp:xslt-eval($xsl,$xml)
```

Answer (score 0):

MarkLogic covers parts of XQuery 3.0 (with its 1.0-ml dialect), but unfortunately FLWOR group by support is lacking.

However, you can still programmatically create group by like syntax which will achieve the same results. Here is an XQuery example:

```
for $d in distinct-values(doc("order.xml")//item/@dept)
let $items := doc("order.xml")//item[@dept = $d]
order by $d
return <department code="{$d}">{
         for $i in $items
         order by $i/@num
         return $i
       }</department>
```

HTH

Comment: MarkLogic 5 doesn't support group by.

Comment: You could speed up this approach using `cts:values` (instead of distinct-values), and `cts:search` (instead of XPath predicates), particularly if you can store order items as separate files.