# How to using group by function in Xquery

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am using XQuery and I need to convert the (,) sepereated format or using group by in Xquery.

```
Final Output
grp|A|#A
grp|A4|#A
grp|A2|#A
grp|A1|#A


Expected Output

grp|A,A4,A2,A1|#A
```

My Xquery:

```
let $root := 'grp'
let $uri := for $i in fn:collection('collection')
 return fn:document-uri($i)
let $result := for $each-uri in $uri

             let $title := (doc($each-uri)//grp/title/text())[1] 
             let $id  := (doc($each-uri)//grp/@id)[1]
             let $root :=  'grp'
             return fn:concat($root,'|',$id,'|',$title)

         return fn:distinct-values($result)
```

Comment: What did you try, where are you stuck?

Comment: I get the data from XML and concatenate to the pipe symbol , after that #A is  repeated values so again i need to change this format grp|A,A4,A2,A1|#A

Comment: Please share some code..

Comment: Hi grtjn , I have added my code .

Comment: @grtjn , How to solve any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I think only a group-by clause and a `string-join` call were missing.

```
let $root := 'grp'
let $uri := for $i in fn:collection('collection')
            return fn:document-uri($i)
let $result := for $each-uri in $uri
               let $title := (doc($each-uri)//grp/title/text())[1] 
               let $id  := (doc($each-uri)//grp/@id)[1]
               let $root :=  'grp'
               group by $root, $title
               return fn:concat($root,'|',string-join($id, ","),'|',$title)
return fn:distinct-values($result)
```

Although `distinct-values` may need to be moved to the IDs, and `concat` can be replaced with `string-join` as well, like so:

```
let $root := 'grp'
let $uri := for $i in fn:collection('collection')
            return fn:document-uri($i)
let $result := for $each-uri in $uri
               let $title := (doc($each-uri)//grp/title/text())[1] 
               let $id  := (doc($each-uri)//grp/@id)[1]
               let $root :=  'grp'
               group by $root, $title
               return string-join(
                 ($root, string-join(distinct-values($id), ","), $title),
                 '|'
               )
return $result
```

Comment: Thanks  for Query , but I got below issue. XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected QName_

Comment: I think some issue with group by

Comment: I just realized you are using MarkLogic. It does not support the group-by syntax, however, some explanations specific to how to do it in MarkLogic are given in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276436/how-to-use-group-by-in-marklogic I hope it helps!